# How can I set value of primitives in a list?

Tags: javascript

```
var var1;
var var2;
var var3;
var list_var = [var1, var2, var3];
var values = ["hello", "cruel", "world"];
```

I want to have...

```
var1 = "hello"
var2 = "cruel"
var3 = "world"
```

What should I do? In my case I need to have a dynamic list of primitive variables in a list that need to be set accordingly. I want to do this with `for` loop.

Comment: why do you want to do this? arrays are the right data structure for storing a dynamic list of values...

Comment: Not sure if I understood what you wanna do, but, can't you just push the strings into the array in your loop?

Comment: In my case I need to have a dynamic list of primitive variables in a list that need to be set accordingly. I want to do this with for loop. Additionally, I have a function that I can put a list of primitives. In that function new values will be set to each of the primitives in the array.

Comment: If you believe my answer below achieves what you want, would you kindly mark it as the accept answer? If it does not answer your question, i'm happy to provide more help if you can clarify why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use destructuring.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

In your example...

```
var values = ["hello", "cruel", "world"];
var [var1, var2, var3] = values;
console.log(var1, var2, var3)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fnsjrjcv/

Update: You can use this to set variable in an outer scope in the same way you would with a normal variable. By defining them within the outer scope, here is an example:

```
var var1, var2, var3;

function changeMyVars() {
  var values = ["hello", "cruel", "world"];
  [var1, var2, var3] = values;
}

changeMyVars();
```

Comment: Hey mate, I have not yet check your solution. Give me time, later tonight I will check this.

Comment: This solution worked, kinda. But it only changes the variables in their current scope. In my case I put your code in a function, with those primitives  set and declared outside of the function. The variable change is only inside that function.

Comment: I have updated my answer to give an example of how to do what (i think) you seek. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Hey that is perfect! I should have know it actually XD.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be:

```
for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) { 
    eval("var" + i + "=" + values[i]);
}
```

Anyhow, you should be aware that it cannot be a plausible way to use this, based on the situation.

Comment: Whoaaa `eval()`, I guess I have no other option, have I?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window` object to set values of variables at global scope (though not recommended/advised of having variables at global scope). But the `list_var` should have list of variables in string format.

```
var list_var = ["var1", "var2", "var3"];
var values = ["hello", "cruel", "world"];

for (i = 0; i < list_var.length; i++) {
    window[list_var[i]] = values[i];
}

console.log(var1);
console.log(var2);
```